Finding word in sentence without another word
I wrote code that finds in the text all words in the list called "self" and creates a new column (D1$self) that gets a value of 1 if one of the words in the list appears, and 0 if not:
self_cat <- c('illness', 'mood', 'fatigue', 'tension', 'anxiety', 'health')

D1$self <- as.integer(grepl(paste(self_cat, collapse='|'), D1$text1, ignore.case = 
TRUE)) 

I want to add to this list the word "responsibility" (or "responsible" or "iresponsible", etc.), but only if the word "war" is not in the sentence (before or after different "respons").
I tried adding the regex "\bresponsible\b(?!.*war)" but I recieve an error message:
Error in grepl(paste(self_cat, collapse = "|"), D1$text1,  : 
  invalid regular expression 
'sleep|illness|mood|fatigue|tension|anxiety|health|\bresponsible\b(?!.*war), reason 
'Invalid regexp'


Already tried grepl(., perl=TRUE)?

You should use lookarounds in your regexps only with perl=TRUE. Original TRE regex engine used in base R regex functions does not support them.

Another point is that \bresponsible\b(?!.*war) matches responsible whole word if not followed with war string somewhere on the right. If you want to also avoid matching responsible if war appears on the left, please edit the question to reflect this problem (right now, it is just about an invalid regexp, which is a known issue)

@WiktorStribiżew Feel free to re-add regex tag!

@jay.sf Right now, it is really not a regex issue, so unless OP has the problem I described above, there is no need re-adding the regex tag.

can't you try with boolen expressions? like: <word in self OR (contains "responsibility" AND NOT contains "war")>. Maybe not the most elegant approach though...
